# how to get the each id duration using with mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregate, mongoose-schema

Iam trying this mongo db aggregation but not get the correct input anny suggest me

```
 db.lights.aggregate({ $match: {  CREATE_DATE : {$gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:02:30.000Z")} },{$addFields: {  duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}   }} })
```

expected Output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a74843711955836a8b4b5"),
    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"),
    "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:45.000Z"),
    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON"
     "duration":0.00416666666666667

}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a75ac3711955836a8b4c5"),
    "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
    "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:02:30.000Z"),
    "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:02:39.000Z"),
    "STATUS" : "LIGHTS OFF"
    "duration":0.0025

}
```

Comment: Why are you expecting 0.667 in both cases if first one represents one month and second one is just 25 seconds ?

Comment: @ mickl  sorry by mistake both cases are not same please any suggest aggregation  query with me

Comment: You're subtracting two dates which gives you the number of miliseconds between them, for first doc you'll get  `NumberLong("2679300000")` which is roghly 744 hours ~ 31 days which looks okay.

Comment: @ mickl  ya okay i will change the first doc .my expect the out put not getting any wrong the aggregation please check please solve the problem please

Comment: What  is the output you get when you run the query you have ? How is the output that you get is different from your expected output ? Your expected output tells nothing about what you like to achieve.

Comment: @Veeram my expected out put is diffrence from CREATE_DATE-RECEIVEDDATE

Comment: Okay the query you have gives you difference in hours. How is the duration in the expected output  represented ? How is that calculated ?

Comment: @Veeram  each Id 12 hours every day 6pm to 6 am

Comment: What is 0.667465900 ? How is that calculated ?

Comment: @Veeram  sorry by mistake wrong expected out put 
 this is correct out put
2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z-2018-01-24T20:05:45.000Z=0.00416666666666667,
2018-02-24T20:02:30.000Z-2018-02-24T20:02:39.000Z=0.0025,
this is expected out put i write the query something wrong please check the query please any suggestions

Comment: Did you run the query that your have ? That is exactly the output will you get.

Comment: @Veeram no iam not run the query  iam write first query 
db.lights.aggregate([   {$addFields: {       offduration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}   }} ])
output:{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a74843711955836a8b4b5"),
 "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/4",
 "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30Z"),
 "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
 "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON"
}
ofter anothe query write down

Comment: @Veeram db.lights.aggregate([   {$addFields: {       offduration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}   }} ])
output:
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5a9a75af3711955836a8b4c8"),
 "SWITCHID" : "Z4-W40-SS451A/5",
 "CREATE_DATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:30Z"),
 "RECEIVEDDATE" : ISODate("2018-02-24T20:05:45Z"),
 "STATUS" : "LIGHTS ON",
 "offduration" : 0.004166666666666667
}
how to add two aggregate write single query

Comment: what is the problem with the query you have in the post ? It looks like the single query that you want.

Comment: @Veeram db.lights.aggregate({ $match: {  CREATE_DATE : {$gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:02:30.000Z")} },{$addFields: {  duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}   }} })

this  query is not working may be i write the wrong please check any mistake

Comment: query looks good to me. where is the data ? Can you add the data that you are querying ?

Comment: @Veeram  somthing small mistakes in the closing braces and somthing is wrong not get the output i will check please check sir once again

Comment: Okay. Try `db.lights.aggregate([{ $match: {  CREATE_DATE : {$gte: ISODate("2018-01-24T20:05:30.000Z"), $lt: ISODate("2018-02-24T20:02:30.000Z")} }},{$addFields: {  duration: {$divide: [{$subtract: ["$RECEIVEDDATE", "$CREATE_DATE"]}, 3600000]}   }}])`

Comment: its working thank you

Comment: Sir i have small questions i got the duration but same SWICHID number of there how to calculate each id average duration

Comment: I don't know anything about your project. I will need data along with your explanation and I can help you. Please include the data and expected output and create a new question.